# What is the difference between kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" and "private"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, argocd

**strong text** I have a kubernetes cluster with argocd installed, and configured the argocd ingress according to https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/ -> kubernetes/ingress-nginx

However I cannot get it to work unless I set

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

to

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: private
```

My ingress.yaml before replacement:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - argocd.my.example.domain
      secretName: argocd-int
  rules:
    - host: argocd.my.example.domain
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: argocd-server
              port:
                number: 443
```

I am fairly new to Kubernetes, so I am wondering what is the difference between the two?
I just happened to find that difference when comparing the ingress.yaml to another project but did not find any explanation for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kubernetes.io/ingress.class` is mainly used to point the ingress to a specific **ingress controller**.

In Easy understanding if you are running the multiple Ingress controller like Nginx and another one is Apache in single K8s cluster.

When you install the **ingress controller** there is a field to set the name of the **class** which is further used in **ingress** as annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: private` so that ingress is managed by a specific ingress controller(backend) and follows the rules sets.

**Ingress class**

> Ingresses can be implemented by different controllers, often with
> different configuration. Each Ingress should specify a class, a
> reference to an IngressClass resource that contains additional
> configuration including the name of the controller that should
> implement the class.

Read more about the ingress class : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class

**Scenario**

People run the multiple Nginx ingress controller with class names **nginx-internal** and **nginx**, Accordingly creating the ingress to forward & manage the traffic routing in the cluster by specifying the class to ingress rules.

**Nginx-internal** class has an example rule to append one header if traffic flow by that class ingress.

While just for example consider **Nginx** class for public usage so it will allow all headers to the backend or limited headers, it checks for **Auth**, traffic allowed from a few whitelisted IPs only with this class.

So with **ingressclass** you can run the **multiple ingresses** backed by **multiple** **ingress controller** having different rules set.

Incase anyone want to read more about how to update the class name and run multiple ingress controllers please visit: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was something predefined, but I found it now in the ingress installer.